# Why is my executable faster when ran from PyCharm?

Tags: performance, rust, pycharm

I'm experiencing weird performance characteristics with this code depending on how I run it:

```
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let start_time = Instant::now();

    for p in 1..10000000 {
        if prime_check(p as f64) {
            println!("{} is prime", p);
        }
    }
    let end_time = Instant::now();
    let elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
    println!("Elapsed time: {:?}", elapsed_time);
}

fn prime_check(p: f64) -> bool {
    let k: u64 = p.sqrt() as u64;
    for j in 2..=k {
        if p % j as f64 == 0.0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

When I hit Alt+Shift+F10 in PyCharm with the Rust plugin, I get this:

```
9999943 is prime
9999971 is prime
9999973 is prime
9999991 is prime
Elapsed time: 11.537594s
```

When I build and run executable with rustc, I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Proj\Rs\src> rustc -O main.rs 
9999943 is prime
9999971 is prime
9999973 is prime
9999991 is prime
Elapsed time: 37.1560723s
```

I tried adding this to `Cargo.toml` but it made no difference:

```ini
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 3
```

How can I make rustc produced executable as fast as PyCharm? What causes such a difference?

Comment: If you use `rustc`, it won't use whatever you put in Cargo.toml. Why are you not using `cargo run --release`? If you want to enable O3 with `rustc`, do `rustc -C opt-level=3 ...`

Comment: ```Elapsed time: 37.3140651s
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Proj\Rs\src> cargo run --release``` No difference

Comment: Two comments: 1) It's very suspicious that release and debug build run with identical performance. Normally there is a factor of 5-6. 2) The only thing I can think of is that the large number of `println`s are the slowdown. And those might be console dependent; it might be that PyCharm's console can `println` faster than powershell. Try again without the `println`s.

Comment: Third comment: Why do you check our primes as `f64`? This is both inefficient and error prone - rounding errors will give you incorrect results. Use `u64` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your code ran in:

- `cargo run`: `Elapsed time: 267.3377065s`
- `cargo run --release`: `Elapsed time: 212.5371301s`

Now let's run it again without the `println`s, because I suspect those are the main reason why your code is slow. And the fact that your code performs different in PowerShell and PyCharm is because their `println` handling is different.

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let start_time = Instant::now();

    let mut count: u64 = 0;
    for p in 1..10000000 {
        if prime_check(p as f64) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    
    let end_time = Instant::now();
    let elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
    println!("Found {} primes.", count);
    println!("Elapsed time: {:?}", elapsed_time);
}

fn prime_check(p: f64) -> bool {
    let k: u64 = p.sqrt() as u64;
    for j in 2..=k {
        if p % j as f64 == 0.0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

- `cargo run`:

  ```rust
  Found 664580 primes.
  Elapsed time: 54.3782759s
  ```
- `cargo run --release`:

  ```rust
  Found 664580 primes.
  Elapsed time: 30.7077071s
  ```

I suspect the output of this code will now perform similarly in PowerShell and PyCharm.

---

As a further remark, I'd like to mention that your implementation of `prime_check` is dangerous - using `f64` will introduce rounding errors at a certain point, and it will produce incorrect results.

Use `u64` instead:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let start_time = Instant::now();

    let mut count: u64 = 0;
    for p in 1..10000000 {
        if prime_check(p) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    let end_time = Instant::now();
    let elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
    println!("Found {} primes.", count);
    println!("Elapsed time: {:?}", elapsed_time);
}

fn prime_check(p: u64) -> bool {
    let k: u64 = (p as f64).sqrt() as u64;
    for j in 2..=k {
        if p % j == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

```
Found 664580 primes.
Elapsed time: 9.4109272s
```